# Run Rock, Scissor, Paper use break to out of loop not working

Tags: r, if-statement, while-loop

```
> play_games <- function() {
> print("Welcome to Rock, Scissor, Paper challaenge.")
> print("Games Rules : ")
> print("1. Win each match get one score.") 
> print("2. Tie each match zero score.")
> print("3. Lost each match zero score.")
> print("4. If you want to end game type end.")
> 
> choices <- c("Rock", "Scissor", "Paper")
> 
> player_select <- readLines("stdin",  1)
> 
> while(TRUE) {
> ai_select <- sample(choices,  1)
> 
> if ( player_select == "end") {
> print("Thank you for joining") 
> break
>     }
> else if ( (player_select == "Paper") & (ai_select == "Rock"))
>       {
> print("Win get 1 point")
>     }
> else if( (player_select == "Rock") & (ai_select == "Sciccor")) {
> print("Win get 1 point")
>     }
> else if( (player_select == "Scissor") & (ai_select == "Paper")) {
> print("Win get 1 point")
>     }
> else {
> print("Tie get 0 point")
>     }
>   }
> }
> 
> play_games()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a matching matrix `m`, which we also use to `sample` from. We look if row-`match`es of `player_select` and `ai_select` are the same, i.e. difference is zero. This gives a boolean that we can convert to numeric using `+`. This implements a score of `1` or `0` which will be added to `total`. We also use the score to operate a `switch` by adding `+1` to get first or second switch position. Actually, only if both inputs are `identical` we have a tie, I've slightly changed that rule. I also use `repeat` that we explicitly can `break` if a condition is met. Also `cat` is nicer than `print`, because the output has no quotes.

```
play_games <- function() {
  cat(paste('Games Rules:\n1. Win match get one score.\n2. Tie match',
            'zero score.\n3. Lost match minus one score.\n4. Type "Rock",',
            '"Scissors", "Paper", or "end" to end game.'))
  m <- matrix(c("Paper", "Rock", "Scissors", "Rock", "Scissors", "Paper"), 3)
  score <- 0L; total <- 0L; i <- 0L
  repeat {
    player_select <- readline()
    if (player_select == 'end') break
    ai_select <- sample(m, 1L)
    if (!player_select %in% c(m, 'end')) {
      cat('Invalid input. Please enter "Rock", "Scissors", "Paper", or "end"')
    }
    else if (identical(player_select, ai_select)) {
      cat("Tie get 0 point")
    } else {
      score <- +((match(player_select, m[, 1]) - match(ai_select, m[, 2])) == 0L)
      out <- switch(score + 1L, "You lose, -1 point", "You win, get +1 point")
      total <- total + score
      i <- i + 1L
      cat(out)
    }
  }
  cat(sprintf('Score: %s pts, thank you for joining', 2*total - i))
}
```

### Usage

```
set.seed(42)

play_games()
# Games Rules:
# 1. Win match get one score.
# 2. Tie match zero score.
# 3. Lost match minus one score.
# 4. Type "Rock", "Scissors", "Paper", or "end" to end game.
# Scissors
# You win, get +1 point
# Rock
# You win, get +1 point
# Scissors
# You win, get +1 point
# Paper
# Tie get 0 point
# Scissors
# You lose, -1 point
# Foo
# Invalid input. Please enter "Rock", "Scissors", "Paper", or "end"
# end
# Score: 2 pts, thank you for joining
```